# What is there similar to Properties class of Android in windows phone 8.1..?

Tags: windows-phone-8, configuration, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a file **myapp.properties** in which I have stored some properties as **key/value** pairs. For example

```
ENABLE_READING=false
TIME_TO_DISPLAY=5
ENABLE_COPYING=true
```

How can I read it into my Windows phone 8.1 app...? In Android it does it using the Properties class...Is there somthing similar to it in windows phone 8.1...?
Or if I specify in any other file **other than .properties**, can I achieve it using the exsisting Windows Api's or classes.

Answer (score 1):

Local or Roaming Settings may fit your need:

1. [LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx)
2. [RoamingSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx)

Access them using

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings[...];
```

Comment: I want to read my initial properties from a text file at a specific path in the phone....Ho to do that...? In Local setting I see that we store data into the settings from the app. I just need a way to parse these properties from a text file....

Comment: So something like a config file? I usually just use a class with constants in that case. (The Properties class dies exactly that, it's just auto generated).

Comment: Ya, exactly a config file. But I cant declare it as constants in a class, I have to read it from a config file(a text file, or a .property file as in Android), because I have to test my app with different config files.

Comment: I use #ifdef (compiler directives) to swap the values. You cannot change file included in the package without recompiling anyway.